# Java client using JMS for connecting to IBM MQ Channel of TCP/IP throwing error

Tags: java, ibm-mq

We have a IBM MQ Server 7.5 running on a Windows server machine. Till now we had an IBM MQ JMS client (written in groovy) on Windows for reading messages on a TCP channel.

My problem now is we have to move the Client to a Debian machine.
I have downloaded the IBM MQ Client 7 for Debian.

I am writting a sample code to connect to the Server to read the messages.
I am using the `JmsPutGet.java` example from the IBM site.

The environment is as follows:

1. Java 8
2. `com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.0.4.0.jar`
3. `javax.jms-api-2.0.1`

The error I get is

> ```
> The value specified for the property is not supported.
> Modify the value to be within the range of accepted values.
> FAILURE
> ```

I tried using connection mode `Client` as well, it gives a different error as below:

> ```
> com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'VIMSRRI10' with connection mode 'Client' and host name '172.18.21.5(1415)'.
> Check the queue manager is started and if running in client mode, check there is a listener running. Please see the linked exception for more information.
> Inner exception(s):
> com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2539' ('MQRC_CHANNEL_CONFIG_ERROR').
> com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2539;AMQ9204: Connection to host '172.18.21.5(1415)' rejected. [1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2539;AMQ9547: Type of remote channel not suitable for action requested. [3=IRRICI10.VIMSRRI10]],3=172.18.21.5(1415),5=RemoteConnection.analyseErrorSegment]
> com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2539;AMQ9547: Type of remote channel not suitable for action requested. [3=IRRICI10.VIMSRRI10]
> FAILURE
> ```

Sample java code is:

```
JmsFactoryFactory ff =  JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);
JmsConnectionFactory cf = ff.createConnectionFactory();

// Set the properties
cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, HOST);
cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, PORT);
cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, CHANNEL);
cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_DIRECT_TCPIP);
cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, QMGR);
cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_APPLICATIONNAME, "JmsPutGet (JMS)");
//cf.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP, true);
//cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.USERID, APP_USER);
//cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.PASSWORD, APP_PASSWORD);

// Create JMS objects
context = cf.createContext();
System.out.println("After Context\n");
destination = context.createQueue("queue:///" + QUEUE_NAME);
System.out.println("After Queue\n");
long uniqueNumber = System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000;
TextMessage message = context.createTextMessage("Your lucky number today is " + uniqueNumber);

producer = context.createProducer();
producer.send(destination, message);
System.out.println("Sent message:\n" + message);

consumer = context.createConsumer(destination); // autoclosable
String receivedMessage = consumer.receiveBody(String.class, 15000); // in ms or 15 seconds

System.out.println("\nReceived message:\n" + receivedMessage);
```

Comment: Is your new client app running on the Debian machine, trying to connect to the existing MQ Server running on Windows? If this is the case, then you do need to be running in Client mode. The issue appears to be server configuration related, but if this is the same server as your other apps are using then it may be due to the values you are passing into the connection factory. eg. What is `CHANNEL` set too?

Comment: Currently we have a running MQ client on windows which is connecting to the Server succesfully with same creds/values as I have used. The one which I am writing on Debian is not connecting. CHANNEL - is the name of the channel I am trying to connect to. I have verified it multiple times. All value look correct.

Comment: The channel you connect to must be a `SVRCONN`, the error clearly indicates that `IRRICI10.VIMSRRI10` is not.   The name of the channel itself is in a format common for a `SDR` or `RCVR` channels which are used between two queue managers, not for a MQ client app top connect to.

Comment: @JoshMc you should write that as the answer - very clear (as you say) that this is the problem

Comment: @JoshMc  I checked the properties of the channel I am connecting to, it says channel Type = receiver and protocol = TCP. There is already a running JMS Client with exact same code connecting to the same channel only difference being its running on a windows machine. Am i missing something here? This is my first time working on IBM MQ.

Comment: Clients connect to server connection (`SVRCONN`) channels not receiver (`RCVR`) channels. I am 100% certain you can not find anything in the existing JMS app that specifies that it should connect to a `RCVR` channel. Why do you think the existing app connects to that channel?

Comment: @MoragHughson Thanks for the push, Answer posted :)

Comment: @Shweta - Perhaps you can post your other application details in another question something like, "I don't know what channel my client connection is using. We could look at the code and config of the other application and help you understand what channel it is actually using.

Comment: @Shweta did my answer help you to track down your problem?  Please provide some feedback, for example accept my answer if it helped you, or comment if you want to clarify further.

Comment: thanks to all those who have been commenting and answering. I got hold up in another business priority task, so i didnt get time to check this. I'll try this out after I get time and update here whether it worked or not. Thanks all.

Answer (score 3):

The channel you connect to must be a `SVRCONN`.

The error `reason '2539' ('MQRC_CHANNEL_CONFIG_ERROR')` indicates that the channel you are connecting to is not a `SVRCONN`.

This is spelled out clearer in the next line of the error which also provides the the name of the channel you are attempting to connect to `IRRICI10.VIMSRRI10`:

```
AMQ9547: Type of remote channel not suitable for action requested. [3=IRRICI10.VIMSRRI10]
```

The name of the channel itself is in a format common for a `SDR` or `RCVR` channels which are used between two queue managers, not for a MQ client app to connect to.

Comment: You seem to be right according to this as well: CC=2;RC=2539;AMQ9547: Type of remote channel not suitable for action requested. [3=IRRICI10.VIMSRRI10]

Comment: That appears to be the same MQ reason code (2539) and error message (AMQ9547) in Josh's answer. I am unclear what you mean by "as well"?

Comment: @MoragHughson I added the `AMQ9547` error text also to my answer yesterday since it does give some more detail to support that the channel is NOT a `SVRCONN`.